# Git commits and reference headers

Tags: git, github, git-commit

There exists reference headers for git commits which are in themselves separate commits. For example, there are two commits, say `925ca878bc3c6c264ba5335b39be762a39e462ec` and `035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4`.

When I do a `git show-ref --heads --tags`, I get

```
925ca878bc3c6c264ba5335b39be762a39e462ec refs/heads/035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4

1afff830dc0611c924d3bdaf490b0378dd4f2444 refs/heads/4d04fde758564386fb5d6922a1d4f01970e4e050

925ca878bc3c6c264ba5335b39be762a39e462ec refs/heads/af76057dea6c0f395fa2eada0e45dd8c01a4aea6
```

So now after a checkout on `925ca878bc3c6c264ba5335b39be762a39e462ec`, if I try to checkout `035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4`, I get

```
warning: refname '035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4' is ambiguous.
```

I am already using two commands `rm -f .git/index.lock` and `git branch -D $(git branch --merged | grep -v \* | xargs)` (Ideally, these should deal with the branch issue) prior to every individual commits.

Is there a workaround? I didn't run into this earlier, so I am unsure as what exactly is happening.

Comment: So you have branches with big long numeric names as if they were hash values? `035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4` is the name of a branch??

Comment: and why does this sha1 does not have the correct size?

Answer (score 1):

You have branches with long hexadecimal names, which is odd. If you run `git branch` you should see something like this.

```
035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4
4d04fde758564386fb5d6922a1d4f01970e4e050
af76057dea6c0f395fa2eada0e45dd8c01a4aea6
```

Presumably there is a commit with the ID of `035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4` as well.

If this is deliberate it's not a good idea for the reasons you've just discovered. If you must do it, disambiguate the branch name with a prefix like `branch/035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4`.

If this is a mistake, then you're somehow creating branches using commit IDs as the name. It's possible you have the syntax of `git branch` backwards. It's supposed to be this.

```
git branch <name> <branch from>
```

Making a branch off of commit `035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4` would be

```
git branch thename 035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4
```

It's possible you're doing

```
git branch 035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4 035d1c4e0d4be18bf8f46150072d1c4e0d4
```

Or even just

```
git branch <the current commit>
```

Possibly this in some script somewhere

```
git branch $(git rev-parse HEAD)
```